# Apache reverse proxy content-length

Tags: javascript, css, apache, jsp

All,

I almost successfully implemented a parser on Apache/2.2.15, see part of my virtual host config included.

Problem I still encounter is when is perform a get to the two urls included

"GET /html/js/everything.jsp?browserId=ie&themeId=newTangoModuleTheme_WAR_newTangoModuleTheme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&languageId=fr_FR&b=6120&t=1364288620000 HTTP/1.1" 200 1001584

"GET /html/js/everything.jsp?browserId=ie&themeId=classic&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&languageId=fr_FR&b=6120&t=1364288620000 HTTP/1.1" 200 1001584

I always receive a conten-length mismatch of two bytes, response header indicates 1001582 but server returns 1001584, as a consequence page is not loaded properly.

All information is more then welcome.

FYI- other js and css pages are rendered correctly only the two jsp pages provide problems !!!

```
     <VirtualHost ip address>

       KeepAlive On
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteLogLevel 4
       RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
       AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
       ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
   LogLevel Debug

   ServerName srvname

# load additional modules to adjust responses
 LoadFile      /usr/lib64/libxml2.so
LoadModule    proxy_html_module       modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule    xml2enc_module          modules/mod_xml2enc.so

# Hacked by KR in order to allow full content parsing
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

# Amigo here's the declaration for W3C HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0

ProxyHTMLLinks  a               href
ProxyHTMLLinks  area            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  link            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  img             src longdesc usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  object          classid codebase data usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  q               cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  blockquote      cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  ins             cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  del             cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  form            action
ProxyHTMLLinks  input           src usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  head            profile
ProxyHTMLLinks  base            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  script          src for
ProxyHTMLLinks  frame           src longdesc
ProxyHTMLLinks  iframe          src longdesc
ProxyHTMLLinks  body            background
ProxyHTMLLinks  applet          codebase

ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
                onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
                onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
                onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

ProxyHTMLEnable On
#ProxyHTMLExtended On
#ProxyHTMLMeta On
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://www.site1.be
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://www.site2.be

</VirtualHost>
```

Regards,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

I was having some issues with the `Content-Length` header being incorrectly set when `ProxyHTMLEnable On` was set. What corrected the problem for me was including `proxy-html` at an appropriate point the output filter list. In my case I was using some other filters you may or may not be using, and the line in the Apache configuration file was:

```
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
```